# Проблема генерации ссылки

Tags: php, ссылка

Коротко и ясно есть код:

```
$url = 'https://pay.freekassa.ru/?m='.$merchant_id.'&oa='.$order_amount.'&o='.$order_id.'&s='.$sign.'&currency='.$currency.'&us_login='.$us_login.'&lang=ru';
```

суть проблемы, у меня генерируется ссылка

```
https://pay.freekassa.ru/?m=*****&oa=*&o=*&s=**********¤cy=RUB&us_login=*&lang=ru
```

**вместо**

```
https://pay.freekassa.ru/?m=*****&oa=*&o=*&s=**********&currency=RUB&us_login=*&lang=ru
```

Кто не понял в чём разница, генерируется `¤cy=` вместо `&currency=`
Как пофиксить?

Comment: [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: у меня с тестовыми значениями ваш код нормально работает -_-

Comment: s в студию, или используйте [http_build_query()](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.http-build-query.php#refsect1-function.http-build-query-examples)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуй всё-ж по правельному ссылку собрать, темболее что PHP это умеет делать из коробки.

```php
$url = 'https://pay.freekassa.ru/?' .
    http_build_query([
        'm' => $merchant_id,
        'oa' => $order_amount,
        'o' => $order_id,
        's' => $sign,
        'currency' => $currency,
        'us_login' => $us_login,
        'lang' => $lang
    ]);
```

Если что-то не получаеться в переменных, то стоит обратится к документации.

- https://docs.freekassa.ru/#section/1.-Vvedenie/1.5.-Formirovanie-podpisi-v-platezhnoj-forme